# sapui5, MessageToast.show is not a function, although sap/m/MessageToast has already been imported

Tags: sapui5

I would like to display a messager in sapui5 Application, when onSave is printed or at the init function ist started. but i have always a error in the console and the messageToast do not work.

Errormessage in console:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: MessageToast.show is not a function

this is my controller.js:

```js
sap.ui.define(['sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller', 
 'timeTrackertimeTracker/controller/BaseController', 
 'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel', 
 "sap/m/MessageToast",
 "sap/ui/model/odata/ODataModel",
 "sap/ui/core/routing/History"
 ],


     function(Controller, BaseController, MessageToast, JSONModel, ODataModel, History) {
     "use strict";

     //Global variables
     //var _oController, oModel, oView;
     var Calendarcontroller = BaseController.extend("timeTrackertimeTracker.controller.Calendarform", {
     
  /* =========================================================== */
  /* lifecycle methods                                           */
  /* =========================================================== */

      
  onInit: function() {
    //Store controller reference to global variable
    this.getRouter().getRoute("Calendarform").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
    MessageToast.show("init");
  }, 
    

  
  /* =========================================================== */
  /* event handlers                                              */
  /* =========================================================== */
  
  _onRouteMatched: function() {
   // register for metadata loaded events
   var oModel = this.getModel("appointments");
   oModel.metadataLoaded().then(this._onMetadataLoaded.bind(this));
  },
  
  _onMetadataLoaded: function () {
   // create default properties
    var oProperties = {
    Id: "Id" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000000)
/*    duration: "",
    resttime: "",
    title: "",
    starttime: "",
    endtime: "",
    Description: ""*/
   };

   // create new entry in the model
   this._oContext = this.getModel("appointments").createEntry("/appointments", {
    properties: oProperties
    ,
    success: this._onCreateSuccess.bind(this)
   });

   // bind the view to the new entry
   this.getView().setBindingContext(this._oContext, "appointments");

   

  },
  
  onSave: function(oEvent) {
   
          
   // bind the view to the new entry
   //this.getView().setBindingContext(this._oContext);

   this.getModel("appointments").submitChanges();
  
  }, 
  
  _onCreateSuccess: function (oEvent) {
   // navigate to the new product's object view
   this.getRouter().navTo("AppointmentsList", true);
 
   // unbind the view to not show this object again
   this.getView().unbindObject();
   
   // show success messge
/*   var sMessage = this.getResourceBundle().getText("newObjectCreated", [ oEvent.Id ]);
   MessageToast.show(sMessage, {
    closeOnBrowserNavigation : false
   });*/
  },
  

/*  _onCreateSuccess: function (oAppointment) {
   // show success messge
   var sMessage = this.getResourceBundle().getText("newObjectCreated", [ oAppointment.Title ]);
   MessageToast.show(sMessage, {
    closeOnBrowserNavigation : false
   });
  },
  */

  onCancel: function() {
   this.onNavBack();
   //this.getView().getModel("appointments").deleteCreatedEntry(this._oContext);
  },
  
  
  /**
   * Event handler for navigating back.
   * It checks if there is a history entry. If yes, history.go(-1) will happen.
   * If not, it will replace the current entry of the browser history with the worklist route.
   * @public
   */
  onNavBack : function() {

/*   var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
   oRouter.navTo("AppointmentsList");*/
   
   
   var oHistory = History.getInstance(),
    sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();

   // discard new product from model.
   this.getModel("appointments").deleteCreatedEntry(this._oContext);

   if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
    // The history contains a previous entry
    history.go(-1);
   } else {
    // Otherwise we go backwards with a forward history
    var bReplace = true;
    this.getRouter().navTo("AppointmentsList", {}, bReplace);
   }
  }

     });
     
     return Calendarcontroller;
     
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Exchange places of parameters `MessageToast` and `JSONModel` in function (line 9): in the dependency list `sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel` mentioned before `sap/m/MessageToast`